# Search in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array called myArray :

> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;

The NSLog of myArray is :

> 2014-09-09 11:25:24.108 MyApp[8139:60b] The array is : (
>           (
>           35,
>           John,
>           Davis,
>           14,
>           1
>       ),
>           (
>           36,
>           Harry,
>           Doe,
>           21,
>           1
>       ),
>           (
>           37,
>           Mike,
>           Bravo,
>           22,
>           1
>       ) )

I want to test if a firstName exist in myArray. For example : if "Mike" exist in myArray... How can I do that ? It's certainly easy but I don't know how to do that...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you please describe the objects that are in the array? are they a custom object?

Comment: Can you clear up what is going on here please. What is myObject? Also, that doesn't look like an `NSArray` in the NSLog (I think...). Can you explain the array structure please.

Comment: Your array seems like an array of arrays, and not dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it looks like your array is an array of arrays. Bit strange storing the data that way but you can do something like this...

```
- (BOOL)doesArray:(NSArray*)array containName:(NSString *)name
{
    for (NSArray *propertyArray in array) {
        if ([propertyArray containsObject:name]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

That will tell you if the array contains the given text.

You can filter it using something similar too if you need.

```
- (NSArray *)filterArray:(NSArray *)array containingName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(NSArray *propertyArray, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [propertyArray containsObject:name];
    }];

    return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

The array returned by this will contain any arrays that contain the given text.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)

{
    NSArray *subArray=[array objectAtIndex:i];

    for(int j=0;j<subArray.count;j++)
    {
       MyObject *obj=[subArray objectAtIndex:j];
       if(array containsObject:obj.firstName)
    {
      [self.filteredArray addObject:obj];
    }

}
```

It looks more code..But Hope it helps you..!